# import.meta.glob won't bundle assets from node_modules folder if there are other folders

Tags: laravel, vite

I'm using Laravel 10 and Vite. I'm trying to bundle images that come from a node package and images that come from the resources subfolders.

If I write

```
import.meta.glob([
    '/node_modules/special-images/**',
]);
```

Vite will bundle the images inside the `special-images` folder.
If I add one or more subfolders from resources, only assets in resources folders will be bundled and the images coming from the `node_modules/special-images` folder will be ignored.

```
import.meta.glob([
    '/node_modules/special-images/**',
    '/resources/images/**',
    '/resources/images-bis/**',
]);
```

I wanted to see if the problem was just the resources folder getting some kind of priority, so I created a folder called `magic_folder` and put some images into it. Then if I try to bundle it with the resources folders:

```
import.meta.glob([
    '/resources/images/**',
    '/resources/images-bis/**',
    '/magic_folder/*',
]);
```

the assets from the `magic_folder` and `resources/images` will be bundled while `/resources/images-bis/` will be ignored.

I want to be able to bundle assets that come from multiple folders, in this case from both from node packages and from the resources folder. I expected vite to bundle the assets in the specified folders but I'm clearly not understanding how folders are selected.

Comment: After you remove bundle folder and restart `npm run dev` also same output?

Comment: @502_Geek the problem happens when I do `npm run bundle`

Comment: This could be useful https://github.com/vitejs/vite/discussions/12191 you can try with wildcard folder name